# IoC in React without typescript

Tags: reactjs, ioc-container, inversifyjs

I'm pretty new to React, and I would essentially have a service (one single instance) that I could somehow inject and use in multiple React components.

So far, the options I've come across by googling were:

- Using React's context, but it's not recommended, because it is an undocumented API.
- Passing the object along in the props, from component to component, but it feels a bit inelegant and tedious
- Using an IoC container, such as inversifyJS, who looks great, only it relies on typescript, and I don't wish to write my React app in typescript.

Now, Inversify can apparently be used in vanilla JS, with `inversify-vanillajs-helpers`, but when I tried using it in React to resolve a component (my `App` component), it kept throwing an exception stating

> "Missing required @injectable annotation in: ReactComponent"

So, I'm trying to figure out a way to get an instance of my service (the same instance shared across the few components that use it), either by making inversify work with React but without typescript, or a new approach I haven't explored yet.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can make high order service components and then wrap your React components with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you can do if you don't like TypeScript:

First, you are going to need the [`inversify.decorate`](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/javascript.md#inversify-with-es5) method.

Second, this method is probably going to be too verbose for you. We created a helper called [`inversify-vanillajs-helpers`](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-vanillajs-helpers) for that reason.

And third, React doesn't play nicely with constructor injection so we created a helper to facilitate lazy property injection called [`inversify-inject-decorators`](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-inject-decorators).

Those three tools should lead yo to the desired result :)

Comment: unfortunately, it seems inversify-inject-decorators requires TypeScript. Is there a vanillaJS version of the package ? couldn't find any. Or perhaps a way to use decorate in order to annotate properties for property injection ?

Comment: Status update:  I tried annotating my React component with ``inversify-vanillajs-helpers``, and as it still wasn't working, I tried to remove all injected dependencies (and adapted the call to ``annotate`` to reflect that.) Then, I tried to resolve the controller (with no dependency being injected) and I still have the same message: Missing required @injectable annotation in: ReactComponent. (note that if I don't call annotate, I have a similar message, but it mentions ``App``, not ``ReactComponent``.)

Comment: if I use the vanillajs helpers package to annotate ReactComponent as well, then I get a new error message: 

_The number of constructor arguments in the derived class App must be >= than the number of constructor arguments of its base class._

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply... you are correct, at the moment this is not supported. I recommend you to close this SO question we will deal with this on GitHub as it is a feature request (not a question). You can follow the process of implementation at https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/489